# NavMeshAgent.CalculatePath produces a PathInvalid result

Tags: unity, navmesh

Anyone know what can cause `NavMeshAgent.CalculatePath` to return false and give a path with `PathInvalid` status?

- I have two characters; each character has a NavMeshAgent.  Character x is a standard Humanoid, character Y is a vehicle with a custom agent type.
- Characters start out in scene A, which has two NavMeshes, one for each type, and both are able to navigate just fine.
- Characters get moved to DontDestroyOnLoad so that scene A can be unloaded and scene B can be loaded.
- Scene B has two NavMeshes, one for each type.
- Characters are placed on the ground, on a valid NavMesh location.
- NavMeshAgent is asked to path to another valid location on the NavMesh.  Character Y (the weird one) paths just fine, but for character X, the call to `CalculatePath` fails and the `NavMeshPath` object's status is `PathInvalid`.

I honestly have no idea what's going on here.  If anything, I'd expect pathing to work for X and fail for Y, due to it being a nonstandard (and larger) agent.  Not sure if the scene change is relevant or not; including it just in case it is, and to show that the basic setup is working for 3/4 scenarios here.
Anyone know how to go about debugging this?

Comment: "Not sure if the scene change is relevant or not" - can you reproduce the problem without the scene change? What's the value of X's `isOnNavMesh` property when you start to path? Have you tried working with the `navMeshOwner` to verify X is trying to path on the correct navmesh?

Comment: @DMGregory `isOnNavMesh` is true, `navMeshOwner` is null.  (Which seems like quite the odd combination!)  When I hack it to start out with the character in Scene B, everything works correctly and `navMeshOwner` is the `NavMeshSurface` like you'd expect.